# Does trigger.io allow development of Android homescreen widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, trigger.io, android-appwidget, homescreen

I'm very interested in the [trigger.io](http://trigger.io) platform as an alternative to Xamarin.

One of the key features of my app on Android clients will be a homescreen widget and would also like integration with Daydream.  Xamarin supports development of these components and code examples of widgets are available on their site.

Is it possible to develop a homescreen widget using trigger.io?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I haven't tried or seen it in production yet, I'm pretty sure this can be realized with [Trigger.io's native module platform](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html). You should be prepared to do some native Android programming.

You probably also need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml and other files for that. Use [postbuild hooks](https://trigger.io/docs/current/tools/hooks.html) to change things after the Trigger.io app has been build.

My advice is to dive into (a) how Trigger.io modules are working and (b) how homescreen widgets can be added to an Android app. There are many tutorials for (b). As soon as you feel comfortable with both, try to mix it up.